# Java: Why aren't variable parameters updating as expected in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, instantiation

Based on my code below, When I debug and I get to the point in `me`(jurl instance), where `con.setRequestMethod(method)` is called, the Variables tab first shows:

```
Name            Value
-----------     ----------------------------------------        
this            jurl (id=128)
  -con          HttpsURLConnectionImpl (id=129)
    -method     "GET" (id=116)

method          "POST" (id=118)
furl            "https://www.someurl.com/login" (id=117)
```

If I'm to understand correctly then, shouldn't `con.setRequestMethod("POST")` change this.con.method (id 116) from "GET" to "POST"?  Because it's not.  As soon as debug passes `con.setRequestMethod(method)`, this.con.method still says "GET".  So either I'm missing something here, or Eclipse's variable tracker is bugged.

View.java

```
public Class View {
  private AccountManager accountManager = new AccountManager(this);

  private void login() {
    String username = textuser.getText();
    String password = textpass.getText();
    String locid = getLocId();
    Hashtable result = null;

    result = accountManager.login(username, password, locid);
  }  
}
```

AccountManager.java

```
public class AccountManager {
  public View Parent = null;
  private String USERNAME = null;
  private String PASSWORD = null;
  private String locid = null;

  public View Parent = null;

  public AccountManager(View view) {
    this.Parent=view;
    this._locationAssistant = l;
  }

  public Hashtable login(String username, String password, String locid) {
    final String USERNAME = username;
    final String PASSWORD = password;
    this.USERNAME = username;
    this.PASSWORD = password;
    Hashtable result = new Hashtable();

    URLVisitor vis = new URLVisitor();
    vis.setURL("https://www.someurl.com/login");
    vis.setMethod("POST");
    vis.execute();
  }
}
```

URLVisitor.java

```
public class URLVisitor {
  private String method= "GET";
  private String url;
  public jurl me = null;

  public URLVisitor() {
  }

  public void setURL(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  public void setMethod(String method) {
    this.method = method;
  }

  public void execute() {
    me = new jurl(this.method, this.url);
  }
}
```

jurl.java

```
public class jurl {
  private URL url;
  private HttpURLConnection con = null;

  public jurl(String method, String furl) {
    try {
      url new URL(furl);
      con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      con.setRequestMethod(method);    
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it really mater? Does it actually send a POST? If it still sends a GET, then that's a problem. If it doesn't, you're all good, it's just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. When the original `HttpURLConnection con`, is created, `con.method`'s default value is `"GET"`.  When `con.setRequestMethod` is called, however, for `me`, which is an instantiation that is created inside the already running `vis` instantiation, it's `con.setRequestMethod("POST")` is not reflected in `vis.me.con.method`, but instead one level down in `vis.me.con.delegate.method`.

Answer (score 0):

> As soon as debug passes con.setRequestMethod(method), this.con.method still says "GET".

You can't expect the field to change until *after* the `setRequestMethod` call returns.  It sounds to me like the debugger is behaving normally / correctly.

It is also possible that I've misunderstood you, and that you are really seeing a stale value for that field.  Try getting the debugger to refetch the value from the field.

---

But this should not affect the way that the code actually behaves, whether your are running it from the debugger or not.

Finally, note that your code doesn't actually call `connect` or attempt to look at the status or content, so it is academic what the state of the `method` field is.  It won't be used ...

Comment: I've updated the original post with a screenshot.  As you can see, the `setRequestMthod` has already completed and returned, but the variable tab above still says "GET" instead of "POST."  If you want me to also post a shot of the `method` parameter being passed to `setRequestMethod`, I can do that too, but I assure you that it is `POST`.

Comment: I have to be missing something. If I use `con.setRequestMethod("POST"), the variable tab stays as `GET` for `this.con.method`.  But if I output the result of `con.getRequestMethod()`, it says "POST` as it should.  Am I looking at the wrong `method` under this.con?  Or is the variable tracker not updating correctly?

Comment: Have you tried getting the debugger to update?  Have you tried adding some code to fetch and print the value?  Are you actually sending the request??

Comment: yes. As I mentioned in my last comment, I fetched it using `con.getRequestMethod()` and assigned it to a new String variable.  Then used `System.out.println()` to display it to the console. And it correctly showed '"Post"', but `this.con.method` still showed '"GET"'.  I'll try updating if you explain how to do that.

Comment: *"I'll try updating if you explain how to do that."*.  For example, select a different frame and look at its variables, and then select back.